# Convert Arduino code for ultrasonic sensor to android code to be used with IOIO board

Tags: android, arduino, sensors, code-conversion, arduino-ultra-sonic

Is it possible to get the ardunio code for the Me Ultrasonic Sensor in android format?
The code comes from the manufacturer in arduino format but I need to have it in android to be hooked up to a IOIO board not an arduino. I have no I idea how to go about converting it or using it to write my own code from the beginning.

The Code is shown below.
* responses from anyone will be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * \par Copyright (C), 2012-2016, MakeBlock
 * \class MeUltrasonicSensor
 * \brief   Driver for Me ultrasonic sensor device.
 * @file    MeUltrasonicSensor.cpp
 * @author  MakeBlock
 * @version V1.0.2
 * @date    2016/06/25
 * @brief   Driver for Me ultrasonic sensor device.
 *
 * \par Copyright
 * This software is Copyright (C), 2012-2016, MakeBlock. Use is subject to license \n
 * conditions. The main licensing options available are GPL V2 or Commercial: \n
 *
 * \par Open Source Licensing GPL V2
 * This is the appropriate option if you want to share the source code of your \n
 * application with everyone you distribute it to, and you also want to give them \n
 * the right to share who uses it. If you wish to use this software under Open \n
 * Source Licensing, you must contribute all your source code to the open source \n
 * community in accordance with the GPL Version 2 when your application is \n
 * distributed. See http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 *
 * \par Description
 * This file is a drive for Me ultrasonic sensor device, It supports ultrasonic sensor
 * V3.0 provided by the MakeBlock.
 *
 * \par Method List:
 *
 *    1. void MeUltrasonicSensor::setpin(uint8_t SignalPin)
 *    2. double MeUltrasonicSensor::distanceCm(uint16_t MAXcm)
 *    3. double MeUltrasonicSensor::distanceInch(uint16_t MAXinch)
 *    4. long MeUltrasonicSensor::measure(unsigned long timeout)
 *
 * \par History:
 * <pre>
 * `<Author>`         `<Time>`        `<Version>`        `<Descr>`
 * Mark Yan         2015/09/04     1.0.0            Rebuild the old lib.
 * Mark Yan         2015/11/16     1.0.1            Increase 100us delay, avoid ultrasonic read exception.
 * Mark Yan         2016/06/25     1.0.2            Modify Read mechanism of ultrasonic waves.
 * </pre>
 *
 * @example UltrasonicSensorTest.ino
 */
#include "MeUltrasonicSensor.h"

#ifdef ME_PORT_DEFINED
/**
 * Alternate Constructor which can call your own function to map the ultrasonic sensor to arduino port,
 * no pins are used or initialized here.
 * \param[in]
 *   None
 */
MeUltrasonicSensor::MeUltrasonicSensor(void) : MePort(0)
{

}

/**
 * Alternate Constructor which can call your own function to map the ultrasonic Sensor to arduino port
 * \param[in]
 *   port - RJ25 port from PORT_1 to M2
 */
MeUltrasonicSensor::MeUltrasonicSensor(uint8_t port) : MePort(port)
{

}
#else // ME_PORT_DEFINED
/**
 * Alternate Constructor which can call your own function to map the ultrasonic Sensor to arduino port,
 * it will assigned the signal pin.
 * \param[in]
 *   port - arduino port(should analog pin)
 */
MeUltrasonicSensor::MeUltrasonicSensor(uint8_t port)
{
  _SignalPin = port;
  _lastEnterTime = millis();
  _measureFlag = true;
  _measureValue = 0;
}
#endif // ME_PORT_DEFINED

/**
 * \par Function
 *   setpin
 * \par Description
 *   Reset the ultrasonic Sensor available PIN by its arduino port.
 * \param[in]
 *   SignalPin - arduino port for sensor read(should analog pin)
 * \par Output
 *   None
 * \return
 *   None
 * \par Others
 *   None
 */
void MeUltrasonicSensor::setpin(uint8_t SignalPin)
{
  _SignalPin = SignalPin;
  _lastEnterTime = millis();
  _measureFlag = true;
  _measureValue = 0;
#ifdef ME_PORT_DEFINED
  s2 = _SignalPin;
#endif // ME_PORT_DEFINED
}

/**
 * \par Function
 *   distanceCm
 * \par Description
 *   Centimeters return the distance
 * \param[in]
 *   MAXcm - The Max centimeters can be measured, the default value is 400.
 * \par Output
 *   None
 * \return
 *   The distance measurement in centimeters
 * \par Others
 *   None
 */
double MeUltrasonicSensor::distanceCm(uint16_t MAXcm)
{
  long distance = measure(MAXcm * 55 + 200);
  if(distance == 0)
  {
    distance = MAXcm * 58;
  }
  return( (double)distance / 58.0);
}

/**
 * \par Function
 *   distanceInch
 * \par Description
 *   Inch return the distance
 * \param[in]
 *   MAXinch - The Max inch can be measured, the default value is 180.
 * \par Output
 *   None
 * \return
 *   The distance measurement in inch
 * \par Others
 *   None
 */
double MeUltrasonicSensor::distanceInch(uint16_t MAXinch)
{
  long distance = measure(MAXinch * 145 + 200);
  if(distance == 0)
  {
    distance = MAXinch * 148;
  }
  return( (double)(distance / 148.0) );
}

/**
 * \par Function
 *   measure
 * \par Description
 *   To get the duration of the ultrasonic sensor
 * \param[in]
 *   timeout - This value is used to define the measurement range, The
 *   default value is 30000.
 * \par Output
 *   None
 * \return
 *   The duration value associated with distance
 * \par Others
 *   None
 */
long MeUltrasonicSensor::measure(unsigned long timeout)
{
  long duration;
  if(millis() - _lastEnterTime > 23)
  {
    _measureFlag = true; 
  }

  if(_measureFlag == true)
  {
    _lastEnterTime = millis();
    _measureFlag = false;
    MePort::dWrite2(LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    MePort::dWrite2(HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    MePort::dWrite2(LOW);
    pinMode(s2, INPUT);
    duration = pulseIn(s2, HIGH, timeout);
    _measureValue = duration;
  }
  else
  {
    duration = _measureValue;
  }
  return(duration);
}
```

Comment: look at a few arduino examples and code it yourself for android; it's a simple and straight-forward routine that only needs a few lines of code; no "drivers" or libs needed.

Comment: You can't actually notify people with comments like that, and it is *very much frowned upon* by our community to try and draw attention to your question from specific people. I've removed the comments here as they were just noise (the intended recipients never saw them). You can only ping people that have *actually participated with this post*, not anyone else.